# SQL - Conditional column selection in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not sure if this scenario can be achieved using TSQL. I have a table called WorkingDays, which have this info

```
ID  |  EmployeeId |  Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1           | 2       | 2       | 3         | 6        | 5
2   | 2           | 1       | 7       | 5         | 2        | 3
```

The days columns store Ids of WorkingSchedule table, which has this columns:

```
ID          int    Primary Key
StartTime   time
EndTime     time
```

So what I need id get the StartTime and EndTime of an employee depending on the current date.

What I need to get from query is the start and end time depending on the day. The day I want to filter is de current date (using `getdate()` function)

So need to select the correct day column name to make the join.

How can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can provide a sample output based on the above data

Comment: what is that id in the workingdays table. If it is that table id then how can same employee  can contain two different workingschedule ids, I mean two rows for same emp id

Comment: There is only one employee per row! And every employee has given hours for every weekday. So the question is clear. We also don't need an example output as the question is about the way of joining, right, not the exact result. As far as I got it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic sql version:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) ='
select 
    t.EmployeeId
  , StarTime = max(case when t.rn=1 then '+quotename(datename(weekday,getdate()))+' end)
  , EndTime  = max(case when t.rn=2 then '+quotename(datename(weekday,getdate()))+' end)
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by t.EmployeeId order by t.Id)
    from t
    ) t
group by t.EmployeeId;'
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WNH34961

returns:

```
+------------+----------+---------+
| EmployeeId | StarTime | EndTime |
+------------+----------+---------+
|          1 |        5 |       3 |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

---

Depending on how you want the output, here are two other ways that do not use dynamic sql:

Both use [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to unpivot the data, and `WorkDay = datename(weekday,getdate())` to get the current `WorkDay` column.

For one row output we add some conditional aggregation:

```
/* one row per employeeId */
select 
    t.EmployeeId
  , x.WorkDay
  , StarTime = max(case when t.rn=1 then x.Time end)
  , EndTime  = max(case when t.rn=2 then x.Time end)
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by t.EmployeeId order by t.Id)
    from t
    ) t
  cross apply (values 
    ('Monday',Monday),('Tuesday',Tuesday),('Wednesday',Wednesday)
    ,('Thursday',Thursday),('Friday',Friday)
  ) x (WorkDay,Time)
where WorkDay = datename(weekday,getdate())
group by t.EmployeeId, x.WorkDay
```

returns:

```
+------------+---------+----------+---------+
| EmployeeId | WorkDay | StarTime | EndTime |
+------------+---------+----------+---------+
|          1 | Friday  |        5 |       3 |
+------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

---

If you want the output on two rows, like your current output:

```
/* two rows per employeeId */
select 
    t.Id
  , t.EmployeeId
  , x.WorkDay
  , t.StartEnd
  , x.Time
from (
  select *
    , StartEnd = case 
        when row_number() over (partition by t.EmployeeId order by t.Id) = 1 
          then 'StartTime' 
        else 'EndTime' 
        end 
    from t
    ) t
  cross apply (values 
    ('Monday',Monday),('Tuesday',Tuesday),('Wednesday',Wednesday)
    ,('Thursday',Thursday),('Friday',Friday)
  ) x (WorkDay,Time)
where WorkDay = datename(weekday,getdate());
```

returns:

```
+----+------------+---------+-----------+------+
| Id | EmployeeId | WorkDay | StartEnd  | Time |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+------+
|  1 |          1 | Friday  | StartTime |    5 |
|  2 |          1 | Friday  | EndTime   |    3 |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: OK, I read the question several times, and still had no clue  +1

Answer (score 0):

```
select wd.Employee, ws.StartTime, ws.EndTime
  from WorkingDays wd
  join WorkingSchedule ws on ws.Id = case datename(weekday, getdate())
                                      when 'Monday'    then ws.Monday
                                      when 'Tuesday'   then ws.Tuesday
                                      when 'Wednesday' then ws.Wednesday
                                      when 'Thursday'  then ws.Thursday
                                      when 'Friday'    then ws.Friday
                                      else 0
                                     end
```

Hint: `datename(weekday, getdate())` returns you the weekday name in your current locale! This might be better:

```
select wd.Employee, ws.StartTime, ws.EndTime
  from WorkingDays wd
  join WorkingSchedule ws on ws.Id = case datepart(weekday, getdate())
                                      when 1 then wd.Monday
                                      when 2 then wd.Tuesday
                                      when 3 then wd.Wednesday
                                      when 4 then wd.Thursday
                                      when 5 then wd.Friday
                                      else        0
                                     end
```

But then you have to check which day is the first of week (0, 1), depending on your settings.